# Function to correctly display a name

Tags: php, cakephp, frameworks

I want to build an invoicing system in CakePHP. So far so good, but I want to build a function into CakePHP to correctly display the clients name. In an earlier build (just PHP) I builed this (in the User class):

```
function get_display_name(){
    if($this->company){
        return $this->company;
    } else {
        return $this->frontname . ' ' . $this->lastname;
    }
}
```

But I can't get it to work in CakePHP. Or should I do this in the View?

**EDIT**

I've made a CustomerHelper in the Helper folder of CakePHP where I added this:

```
class CustomerHelper extends AppHelper {
    function get_display_name(){
        if($this->Customer->find('company')){
            return $this->Customer->find('company');
        } else {
            return $this->Customer->find('frontname') . ' ' . $this->Customer->find('lastname');
        }
    }
}
```

But I get a fatal error now. "Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object"

Comment: Why doesn't it work? Some kind of error or smth?

Comment: You should post your entire `User` class...

Comment: This sounds like a bad approach for 2.x where models are not objects holding the data directly. Better use find() and a helper/element to format your output correctly. But you need to pass in your customer data array (not trying to make model queries from your helper!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in your data:

```
class CustomerHelper extends AppHelper {
    public function getDisplayName($customer) {
        ///...
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Also note that I corrected it to meet CakePHP coding standards.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!

I hoped that there was a nicer way to do this, but it's fine by me!